# What is static about a base constructor call?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

The following C# code does not compile.

```
public class BaseType
{
    public BaseType(int bar)
    {
        // Do stuff with bar...
    }
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    private int foo;

    public DerivedType() : base(foo = 0) {}
}
```

The error occurs on the call to DerivedType's base constructor, with the message "Cannot access non-static field 'foo' in static context." What is this error message telling me? 'foo' is not static, and neither are the classes, and these are not static constructors.

Comment: I don't think its an exact duplicate, but that's a very helpful link, thanks @mikez.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the point that `base(foo = 0)` executes the `DerivedType` class has not been "Created" yet so it can not access the members it defines yet.

The order things happen is like this

1. The user calls `new DerivedType()`
2. The code calls DerivedType's `base(foo = 0)`
3. The code calls BaseType's implicit `base()` to `Object()`
4. The memory for any fields in `Object` is allocated and then the `Object()` constructor is run to completion.
5. The memory for any fields in `BaseType` is allocated and then the `BaseType(int bar)` constructor is run to completion.
6. The memory for any fields in `DerivedType` is allocated and then the `DerivedType()` constructor is run to completion.

So you see you are attempting to assign a value to `foo` at step 2, but `foo` won't exist till step 6.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the constructor hasn't run yet.

You cannot access your instance until its base type has been constructed.

Comment: I like the way you phrase this!!  The weird part of the error is that it just so happens outside the instance is a static context.

Comment: Technically, you can access an instance field before the base constructor has finished: create a virtual method in base class and call it from base constructor, override in derived class accessing that instance field.

Comment: @fcuesta: Yes, but the base constructor will have _started_.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that `foo` is not static, but only static members of the class and parameters of constructor itself can be used in call to base constructor (in addition to other external constants).

You probably mean

```
public DerivedType() : base(0) {
   foo = 0;       
}
```

To be very precise following in excerpt from C# documentation: section 10.11.1 "Constructor initializers" of C# 5.0 specification.

Access to parameters of the constructor itself allowed:

> The scope of the parameters given by the formal-parameter-list of an instance constructor declaration includes the constructor initializer of that declaration. Thus, a constructor initializer is permitted to access the parameters of the constructor.

But access to instance and hence instance fields is not allowed:

> An instance constructor initializer cannot access the instance being created. Therefore it is a compile-time error to reference this in an argument expression of the constructor initializer, as is it a compile-time error for an argument expression to reference any instance member through a simple-name

Comment: Yes; he's asking _why_.

Comment: @SLaks - I've added restrictions form C# spec. I don't have any insights on "why it was designed this way" (which is generally outside of SO scope), also restrictions seem natural to me.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov see Eric Lippert's answer in the possible dup I linked to. It explains why the language was designed this way.